# Can I embed the Many side of a Spring Data Rest/JPA Bi-directional OneToMany as an Array when GETing the One side

Tags: embed, one-to-many, spring-data-rest, bidirectional

I am exploring Spring Data Rest with a bidirectional mapping. I have two tables One & Many for clarity
**One table**

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "one")
@JsonBackReference
List<Many> many;
```

**Many table**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
@RestResource(exported = false)   
@JoinColumn(name = "one_id")
One one;
```

As expected when I use localhost:8080/manies the One reference is embedded

```
"manies": [
{
"rack": "GF",
"shelf": "2",
   "one": {
   "producer": "Escarpment",
   "name": "Kupe"
},
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8080/manies/1"
},
"many": {
"href": "http://localhost:8080/manies/1"
}
}
},
```

What I am wondering is there any way to do the same with localhost:8080/ones i.e. embed an array of Many
**When I try I can only get a link returned**

```
"ones": [
{
   "producer": "Escarpment",
    "name": "Kupe",
"_links": {
    "self": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/ones/1"},
    "one": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/ones/1"},
    **"many": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/ones/1/many"}**
    }
},
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-projections-excerpts

Comment: Thanks Alan, this works fine.  I was hoping to achieve without projections